# iframe wikipedia article without the wrapper

Tags: javascript, iframe, wikipedia

I want to embed a wikipedia article into a page but I don't want all the wrapper (navigation, etc.) that sits around the articles.  I saw it done here: http://www.dayah.com/periodic/.  Click on an element and the iframe is displayed and links to the article only (no wrapper).  So how'd they do that?  Seems like JavaScript handles showing the iframe and constructing the href but after browsing the pages javascript (http://www.dayah.com/periodic/Script/interactivity.js) I still can't figure out how the url is built.  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The periodic table example loads the printer-friendly version of the wiki artice into an iframe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potasium?**printable=yes**

it's done in *function click_wiki(e)* (line 534, interactivity.js)

> ```
> var article = el.childNodes[0].childNodes[n_name].innerHTML;
> ...
> window.frames["WikiFrame"].location.replace("http://" + language + ".wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=" + encodeURIComponent(article) + "&printable=yes");
> ```

Comment: Not sure why someone bumped you down, but it looks like you are correct.

Comment: me neither. Maybe the actual code snippet is convincing enough ;)

Comment: printable=yes removes the wrapper, but it also removes all images and links. Maybe that's why people bump you down. Now I'm gonna keep trying to find a way to only remove wrapper.

Comment: Nvm, I just noticed that I had checked on a page without any images. This works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Great answer; thanks. If someone needs a regex to change an article url to this flat format, this is a choice: 
var str = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium";
  var patt = new RegExp("^(https:\/\/[a-z]{2,4}\.wikipedia.org\/)wiki\/(.*)");
  var res = patt.exec(str);
  var url= `${res[1]}w/index.php?title=${res[2]}&printable=yes`;

Answer (score 2):

@VolkerK is right, they are using the printable version.

Here is an easy way to find out when you know the site is displaying the page in an iframe.

In Firefox right click anywhere inside the iframe, from the context menu select "This Frame" then "View frame info"

You get the info you need including the Address:

> Address: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chromium&printable=yes

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery library lets you specify part of a page to retrieve by an Ajax call, with a CSS-like syntax: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load

Answer (score -3):

You could always download the site and scrap it. I think everything inside `<div id="bodyContent">` is the content of the article - sans navigation, header, footer, etc..

Don't forget to credit. ;)

Comment: I need it to be a dynamic link so that as people update the article it is updated on my page.