# Pulling text content from Wikipedia - iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, wikipedia

I'm in the process of building a website (using Squarespace) with various pages about people notable enough to have a Wikipedia pages. I have over 150 of these pages, so handwriting bios is pretty time intensive. I'm hoping to pull the text from the introduction of these various figures' Wikipedia pages, so that a) I don't have to write the text myself and b) the information is always updated (which isn't the case with copy and paste).

I've written out the basic format here, for Beyonce's Wikipedia article, which shows the Wikipedia page as normal when run. The height and width values are arbitrary.

```
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyoncé" height="551" width="705"></iframe>
```

Which gives me:

```html
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyoncé" height="551" width="705"></iframe>
```

How might I pull just the text from the page, not the images, sidebars, table of contents, etc. so my website can be visually homogenous? Are iframes even the right tool to use?

Thanks,
K

Comment: you can use the Wikipedia API to get the information on the fly https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

Comment: Dont think iframes are the way to go. You could work with it but would probably run into cross origin issues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe wikipedia article without the wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902/iframe-wikipedia-article-without-the-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to achieve this is by working with Wikipedia API.
For example you could retrieve some data in json format from Wikipeida API
and then format it and save to your database.
JSON:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Beyonc%C3%A9
```

and the same but in HTML representation of the JSON format:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Beyonc%C3%A9
```

if you want to work with `iframe` you could try printer-friendly version of the wiki artice into an iframe.

```
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Beyonc%C3%A9&printable=yes"></iframe>
```

or you can do this with AJAX by calling the wiki api with custom query string parameters.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="article"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=text&page=Beyoncé&callback=?",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
            var blurb = $('<div></div>').html(markup);
            $('#article').html($(blurb).find('p'));

        },
        error: function (errorMessage) {
        }
    });
});
```

[source question for ajax method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577292/is-there-a-way-to-embed-and-style-a-wikipedia-article-in-a-website)
and also [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fm0vxg32/) from this question